# Two '==' equality operators in same 'if' condition are not working as intended

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, operators, equals-operator

I am trying to establish equality of three equal variables, but the following code is not printing the obvious correct answer which it should print. Can someone explain, how the compiler is parsing the given `if(condition)` internally?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i = 123, j = 123, k = 123;
        if ( i == j == k)
                printf("Equal\n");
        else
                printf("NOT Equal\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
manav@workstation:~$ gcc -Wall -pedantic calc.c
calc.c: In function ‘main’:
calc.c:5: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘==’
manav@workstation:~$ ./a.out
NOT Equal
manav@workstation:~$
```

EDIT:

Going by the answers given below, is the following statement okay to check above equality?

```
if ( (i==j) == (j==k))
```

Comment: You need ( (i==j) && (j==k) )

Comment: Your edit tests if `i == j` has the same value as `j == k`.  What happens for `i = 1`, `j = 2`, `k = 3`?  Don't guess, try to figure it out: for example, what is the value of `1 == 2`?

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
  if ( (i == j) == k )

  i == j -> true -> 1 
  1 != 123
```

To avoid that:

```
 if ( i == j && j == k ) {
```

**Don't** do this:

```
 if ( (i==j) == (j==k))
```

You'll get for i = 1, j = 2, k = 1 :

```
 if ( (false) == (false) )
```

... hence the wrong answer ;)

Comment: @Manav, No. Use && between the conditionals.

Comment: It's "fine" but it doesn't make sense. That said "if the equality of `i` and `j` is the same as the equality of `j` and `k`." All three being different would make it true. You want `&&`, which means and.

Comment: No. (i==j) == (j==k) is equivalent to (i==j) ^ (j==k). which means it will be true if i==j and j==k or if i!=j and j!=k.
Because (i==j) returns a true or false value.

Comment: @SurDin, they're not equivalent, they are in fact quite opposite (and only if I ignore the types of the results).

Answer (score 9):

You need to separate the operations:

```
  if ( i == j && i == k)
```

Answer (score 8):

Expression

```
i == j == k
```

is parsed as

```
(i == j) == k
```

So you compare `i` to `j` and get `true`. Than you compare `true` to `123`. `true` is converted to integer as `1`. One is not equal `123`, so the expression is false.

You need expression `i == j && j == k`

Answer (score 7):

I'd heed the compiler's warning and write it as `(i==j) && (j==k)`. It takes longer to write but it means the same thing and is not likely to make the compiler complain.

Comment: Just to be picky, the compiler is actually warning that you're *comparing a comparison*.

Comment: Although that's obviously the meaning Manav intended, that's not the change the compiler suggested. Heeding the compiler's warning would give you this code: `(i == j) == k`.

Comment: True: although the compiler said `suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘==’` but since it didn't specify WHICH '==', I just parenthesised both of 'em! ;)

Comment: More importantly, it does the right thing, while `i == j == k` doesn't.