# Math-like chaining of the comparison operator - as in, "if ( (5<j<=1) )"

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, comparison-operators

```
int j=42;
if( (5<j<=1) ) {
    printf("yes");
} else {
    printf("no");
}
```

Output:

```
yes
```

Why does it output yes?
Isn't the condition only half true?

Comment: You *can* do that, it just doesn't do what the OP thinks (of course, you probably *shouldn't* do that).

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think the output is wrong. What logic did you think the program would follow so that it would print "no"? Your explanation, "because 5" is a bit on the short side.

Comment: This is not what I asked 
The person who edit my question has thought I wrote it wrong
But it is not wrong
He hasn't run the code before edit

Comment: Then what _did_ you mean? The output of the program doesn't depend on the other, unused variables, so removing those only made the problem clearer. And your question, "But I cannot understand How that could happen?" was kept intact, even with the capitalisation error. That leaves the cryptic "because 5"...

Comment: if condition have this (5<j<=1) and it gives yes That was my problem
not (1<j<=5) this condition.
I know (1<j<=5) is gives yes.

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Two '==' equality operators in same 'if' condition are not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2155280/995714)

Answer (score 8):

C does not understand math-like syntax, so

```
if(1<j<=5)
```

is not interpreted as you expect and want; it should be

```
if (1 < j && j <= 5)
```

or similar.

As explained in other answers, the expression is evaluated as

```
 ((1 < j) <= 5)

 =>  ("true" <= 5)

 =>  "true"
```

where "true" (boolean value) is implicitly converted to 1, as explaneid e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion), with references to standards too, and this explain why "true" has to be "less than" 5 (though in C might not be totally correct to speak about "implicit conversion from bool to int")

Comment: +1 for the answer.... but why Menuka Ishan getting the correct answer? m confused

Comment: @Ashish: Implicit conversion from boolean expression to int

Comment: it's explained in other answer: ((1<j) < 5) is evaluated, being 1<j true, and then "true" < 5, true again

Comment: see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion)

Answer (score 6):

[As per operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and LR associativity,

`1<j` evaluates to 1

`1<=5` evaluates to  1

```
if(1)
{ 
  printf("yes")
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit broken, but I believe that the following will clarify what is going on for you:

In C, `1 < j <= 5` means the same thing as `(1 < j) <= 5`. And the value of `1 < j` is 0 or 1 depending on whether is less than or equal to 1 or strictly greater than 1. So here is what happens for a few values of j in your code:

If `j == 0`, this expression is `(1 < 0) <= 5`, which reduces to `0 <= 5` (because `1 < 0` is false). This is a true expression. Your program outputs "yes".

If `j == 3`, this expression is `(1 < 3) <= 5`, which reduces to `1 <= 5` (because `1 < 3` is true). This is a true expression. Your program outputs "yes".

If `j == 6`, this expression is `(1 < 6) <= 5`, which reduces to `1 <= 5` (because `1 < 6` is true). This is a true expression. Your program outputs "yes".

In all cases, your program outputs "yes" because `1 < j` is either 0 or 1, and either way it is less than 5.

What you should have used is `1 < j && j <= 5`.

Answer (score 2):

what you want to write is 
`if ( 1 < j && j <= 5 )`

what is happening in your case is:  `if ( 1 < j <=5 )`
`1 < j` is evaluated first, and it is true so it is evaluated to 1 and your condition becomes
`if (1 <=5)`, which is also true so `printf("yes");` gets excuted