# Double negation in c++ using if

Tags: c++, if-statement

## Problem:

I am practicing from my college's introduction problem set of creating a program where the user introduces four variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and:
if `a` is in `(c; d)` AND `b` isn't in `(c; d)` the program should print `a`, `b` and `a+b`; otherwise it should print `a`, `b` and `a-b`:

I noticed that if the user introduces `a`, `b` such that BOTH statements are false it prints `a+b` instead of `a-b`. Why does it happen?

## Attempt:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {int a,b,c,d;
    cout<<"Introduza a: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Introduzca  b: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Introduzca c: ";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"Introduzca d: ";
    cin>>d;
    if( (c<a<d) && ((b<c || d<b)))
        {cout<<"a= " <<a <<"\n";
        cout<<"b= " <<b << "\n";
        cout<<"a+b= " <<a+b <<"\n";
        }
    else
        {cout<<"a=" <<a <<"\n";
        cout<<"b= " <<b <<"\n";
        cout<<"a-b= " <<a-b <<"\n";}
        }
```

Comment: `(c<a<d)` -- Explain what you're trying to do here.

Comment: `c<a<d` is not doing what you think it's doing. It will first compare `c<a` and then compare the result (0 or 1) to `d`.

Comment: change  `c<a<d` to `c<a && a<d`

Comment: Comparison operators, e.g. `'<'` have operator precedence 9 and *left-to-right* associativity. See [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Consider adopting a standard and more readable formatting style.

Comment: [Math-like chaining of the comparison operator - as in, "if (5<j<=1)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20989496/995714), [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/995714), [Is (val1 > val2 > val3) a valid comparison in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38643022/995714), [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Apart from that one would not indent the braces, it's Horstmann style...

Comment: @Aconcagua The lack of whitespace after the opening brace is the worst though.

Answer (score 2):

in programming languages like C++, C, Java, PHP, .. something like `(c<a<d)` is spread out to `(c < a && a < d)`. The second thing is that you do not need double parenthesizes here `((b<c || d<b))`. This entire line:

```
if( (c<a<d) && ((b<c || d<b)))
```

should look like:

```
if (c < a && a < d && (b < c || d < b))
```

Hope this helps!!!!

CLARIFICATION PER COMMENT:
What I mean in mathematics you write `a < b < c` in programming language you write this as `a < b && b < c`. In programming `a < b < c` is the same as `(a < b) < c` which in turns mean if `a` is less than `b` it will return `1` thus producing `1 < c`. If `a` is greater or equal to `b` `a < b` will return `0` thus producing `0 < c`.

Comment: You should say "In C++", not "In programming". There are programming languages where `c < a < d` actually means `c < a && a < d`.

Comment: "_in programming languages like C++, C, Java, PHP, .. something like `(c<a<d)` is spread out to `(c < a && a < d)`._" But it isn't spread out like this, in language such as C++.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius what do you mean?

Comment: @Gox In the quote, that I quoted, you state, that "_something like `(c<a<d)` is spread out to `(c < a && a < d)`_", which might be read as "`(c<a<d)` is treated as `(c < a && a < d)`". Which isn't the case in C++. It is treated as `((c < a) < d)`. Maybe you wanted to state "_is **not** spread out to_"?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I updated my answer.